# Trying to print only one line of a text document in python

Tags: python, file, text

I am making a program that lets you edit, or read a text document in python, and I'm not finished yet, and I'm stuck on the reading part.  I want it to print only one line, and I'm drawing a blank on how to do so.  The read part is in "def read():"

```
def menu():
    print("What would you like to do?")
    print("\n(1) Write new text")
    print("(2) Read line 3")
    choice = float(input())
    if choice == 1:
        write()
    elif choice == 2:
        read()

def read():
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as read:
        print()

def write():
    print("\nType the full name of the file you wish to write in.")
    file1 = input().strip()
    with open(file1, "a") as add:
        print("What do you want to write?")
        text = input()
        add.write("\n"+ text)

menu()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def read():
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            print(line)
```

---

#### Edit:

```
def read():
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        print lines[1]
```

Comment: That helps a lot, but I'm only trying to print one line in the document, for example line 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the file as an iterable, and loop over it, or you can call `.next()` on it to advance one line at a time.

If you need to read 1 specific line, this means you can skip the lines before it using `.next()` calls:

```
def read():
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
        for _ in range(2):
            f.next()  # skip lines

        print(f.next())  # print the 3rd line
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured mine out pretty late since i do not use the 'def' function, but this prints out the line that you want to print

```
import os.path

bars = open('bars.txt', 'r')
first_line = bars.readlines()
length = len(first_line)
bars.close()
print(first_line[2])
```